# Bash - download a file, log in if required

Tags: bash, curl, download, wget, lynx

I'm using BASH and I need to download a TXT file, which is generated on server-side by request. This means the URL is something like:

```
http://1.1.1.1:4884/page.aspx?fileID=123456&lang=en&Export=1
```

`Export=1` is caught by the .NET application and I'm provided with a TXT file, based on fileID.
In case I haven't logged in, I'm redirected to a login form with `?ReturnUrl` in the URL, redirecting me back to my requested page upon login.

How can I successfully download this file using BASH, `cURL/wget/lynx`. It has to be non-interactive.

I've tried using the `--cookie` options for curl and wget and lynx automation (cmd-log). Lynx worked best, but for some reason, the file download prompt could not be automated.

Please help. If any additional info is required, I will provide.

Comment: `wget` has `--http-password` & `--http-user` options... try them... For more info, check `man wget`... If nothing works, try `expect` utility. You may need to separately install it. (Check `man expect` for more details.)

Comment: I am familiar with expect. How do you think it can be used here? As for the --http-password/user options - they do not support form based authentication.

Comment: Oh, it's form based authentication? it was not mentioned in question, or maybe I missed it...

Answer (score 0):

1. Use curl.
2. Code following approach:

   - try to download the file
   - if failed (redirected to login page), log in and go to begin
3. You always need to use -c option of curl to store the cookies between curl calls
4. To log in using curl you need to know the form on the server, that means: names of fields where you usually type your login and password.
5. To send the data to server use -d option of curl. To send the cookie to server use -b (or --cookie).

Comment: Tried: `anton@hostname ~ $ curl -c -d "txtUsername=admin&txtPassword=admin" http://1.1.1.1:4884/FormLoginAuth.aspx`. Result: source of `FormLoginAuth.aspx` printed to `stdout`. Same result when using `--data="txtUsername=admin&txtPassword=admin"`